# How to differentiate between DOM elements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code that loops over each row of the table and creates a json object. The elements in the rows can be either of the following:

```
<input type="text" id="myelem"/>
```

or

```
<p id="myelem">foo</p>
```

Notice that the `id` attribute for the both is same. This is because on the table there is a button `Add a new Row` when this button is clicked another row is added to the table with a checkbox. When user submits the form the checkbox goes away and the value they entered turns into `<p id="myelem">value they entered</p>`

Below is the code I'm using for this.

```
    $('.input-row').each(function(index, row) {
        var innerObject = {};
        var key = $('#myelem', row).val().toUpperCase();
        jsonObject[key] = "bar";
    });
```

The above works fine for textboxes becuse I'm using the `.val()` function. However, how do I get the data from the row if it contains `<p id="myelem">foo</p>` ??

my pseudo code would be something like this:

```
    $('.input-row').each(function(index, row) {
        var innerObject = {};
        /*
        if #myelem is a text box then use .val()
        if #myelem is a <p> tag then use .html()
        */
        var key = $('#myelem', row).val().toUpperCase();
        jsonObject[key] = "bar";
    });
```

Comment: you should never have duplicate `ID`s.

Comment: I believe it's a violation of specifications to have duplicate id's. id's should be unique on a single page. Duplicate id's can lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: id's should always be globally unique on a page.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Comment: @RuralJuror - The ids MAY be changed but before the user does anything they are duplicates. Use classes.

Comment: duplicate Ids doesn't have much to do with the question. I will still need to determine which type of element I'm dealing with for the current row to find out whether to call .val or .html

Comment: You shouldn't need to use Ids OR classes to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check which type the element is with

```js
var value = null;
if($('#myid').is('input')) {
    value = $('#myid').val();
}
else if($('#myid').is('p')) {
    value = $('#myid').html();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`id`s should always be globally unique on a page.  If you need multiple elements to be referenced, you should use `classes`.  If you set `myelem` as a `class` rather than an `id` you could then reference it like this

```
$('.input-row .myelem')
```

Comment: They are not unique at the point of first display... Use classes.

Answer (score 0):

IDs are unique. You cannot use more than one ID in the same page. If you do so how should you decide which element to use?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery is() eg `if $('#myelem').is ('p'){...}`

Answer (score 0):

If still want to stick your development way then below might help you:

```
$('.input-row').each(function(index, row) {
    var innerObject = {};
    var c = $('#myelem', row);
    var isInputField = c.get(0).tagName.toUpperCase()=="INPUT";
    var key =isInputField ? c.val().toUpperCase():c.html().toUpperCase();
    jsonObject[key] = "bar";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to just get you started. You are using `.each` on class `input-row` but you have not shown the class in your code that you provided. I have used class instead of id in this example. Use it to work ahead.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5HBv/1/)